# Ruby: Deleting all instances of a particular key from hash of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like

```
h = {1 => {"inner" => 45}, 2 => {"inner" => 46}, "inner" => 47}
```

How do I delete every pair that contains the key "inner"?
You can see that some of the "inner" pairs appear directly in `h` while others appear in pairs in `h`

Note that I only want to delete the "inner" pairs, so if I call my mass delete method on the above hash, I should get

```
h = {1 => {}, 2 => {}}
```

Since these pairs don't have a key == "inner"

Comment: First deleting "inner" from h, and then recursing through all nested hashes and deleting "inner"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def f x 
  x.inject({}) do |m, (k, v)|
    v = f v if v.is_a? Hash  # note, arbitrarily recursive
    m[k] = v unless k == 'inner'
    m
  end
end

p f h
```

*Update:*  slightly improved...

```
def f x
  x.is_a?(Hash) ? x.inject({}) do |m, (k, v)|
    m[k] = f v unless k == 'inner'
    m
  end : x
end
```

Comment: The multi-line ternary combined with the block form of `inject` makes your improved solution difficult to read (especially when you combine those with the use of single-letter, nondescript method and variable names). It'd be a bit easier to follow if you used `if/else` instead of the ternary, and meaningful variable names:

```
def reject_keys(input, rejected_key)
  if input.is_a?(Hash)
    input.inject({}) do |hash, (k, v)|
      hash[k] = reject_keys(v) unless k == rejected_key
      hash
    end
  else
    input
  end
end

puts reject_keys(h, "inner")
```

Answer (score 10):

Really, this is what reject! is for:

```
def f! x
  x.reject!{|k,v| 'inner' == k} if x.is_a? Hash
  x.each{|k,v| f! x[k]}
end
```

Answer (score 9):

```
def except_nested(x,key)
  case x
  when Hash then x = x.inject({}) {|m, (k, v)| m[k] = except_nested(v,key) unless k == key ; m }
  when Array then x.map! {|e| except_nested(e,key)}
  end
  x
end
```

Comment: I have been actually needed this solution because I had nested arrays as well! THank you so much!

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with:

```
class Hash
  def deep_reject_key!(key)
    keys.each {|k| delete(k) if k == key || self[k] == self[key] }

    values.each {|v| v.deep_reject_key!(key) if v.is_a? Hash }
    self
  end
end
```

Works for a Hash or a HashWithIndifferentAccess

```
> x = {'1' => 'cat', '2' => { '1' => 'dog', '2' => 'elephant' }}
=> {"1"=>"cat", "2"=>{"1"=>"dog", "2"=>"elephant"}}

> y = x.with_indifferent_access
=> {"1"=>"cat", "2"=>{"1"=>"dog", "2"=>"elephant"}}

> x.deep_reject_key!(:"1")
=> {"1"=>"cat", "2"=>{"1"=>"dog", "2"=>"elephant"}}

> x.deep_reject_key!("1")
=> {"2"=>{"2"=>"elephant"}}

> y.deep_reject_key!(:"1")
=> {"2"=>{"2"=>"elephant"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer but it is a whitelist type approach. For ruby 1.9+

```
# recursive remove keys
def deep_simplify_record(hash, keep)
  hash.keep_if do |key, value|
    if keep.include?(key) 
      deep_simplify_record(value, keep) if value.is_a?(Hash)
      true
    end
  end
end

hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 4}} }
deep_simplify_record(hash, [:b, :c])
# => {:b=>2, :c=>{:b=>2, :c=>{:b=>2, :c=>4}}}
```

Also here are some other methods which I like to use for hashes.
https://gist.github.com/earlonrails/2048705

Comment: There's an edge case: `h = {a: 1, b: {c: 1, a: {b: 2}}}; deep_simplify_record(h, %i[b c])` produces `{:b=>{:c=>1, :a=>{:b=>2}}}`. Not all `:a`s were removed. The `include?` check needs to be done regardless of whether `v` is a `Hash`.